# Add unique to values to foreign key columns

Tags: mysql

I have some tables as follow:

```sql
create table b
(
    pk bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    x int not null,
    y int not null
);

create table a
(
    pk bigint auto_increment
        primary key,

    b__fk bigint null,
    foreign key (b__fk) references b (pk)
);
```

And I want table `a` to have `unique (b.x, b.y)`. I am using MySQL.

The table `b` cannot have `unique (x, y)` as I use it in other ways, I only want this in table `a`, meaning, I do not want any clones of a table `b` row in table `a`.

Comment: Sorry, MySQL does not support indexes or constraints that span multiple tables. You may be able to accomplish what you need with a trigger, or with application code, but those solutions include a risk of race conditions.

Comment: *And I want table a to have unique (b.x, b.y)* Create unique indexes `b (x, y)` and `a (b_fk)`.